# Problema al firmar un nonce para Login con metamask

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

he estado teniendo un problema con una pagina web en la que debo hacer un Login con metamask, similar a lo que aparece aqui:

> https://www.toptal.com/ethereum/one-click-login-flows-a-metamask-tutorial

Para mandar la información me pidieron que fuera en texto plano a travez de un request HTTP POST, lo mando de esta forma:

```
address=0x0a505ea5ca4408078786150d44f5a2034d28b324&signature=0x771f5cd25b2d6ef357cf5d44f3ea79966749d66552a2bef3909272cef2ea640e485da0ff10c505e0cebc2f4462fcc5ab63a9c69ccde24ac5cd42a65a9d5b82b31b
```

Y lo envio al server de esta forma:

```
        return await fetch(
            `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/${BACKEND_URL}/auth/authorize`, {
            body: `address=${publicAddress}&signature=${signature}`,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
            },
            method: 'POST',
        }).then((response) => {return response});
```

Estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo que esta pagina:

> http://orcadefi.com/

El problema es que cuando mando el signature y la address siempre me regresa esto:

```
{
    "state": "error",
    "result": {
        "code": 2004,
        "message": "Signature is invalid"
    }
}
```

Ya comprobe y mandando a llamar el firmado de diferentes formas regresa la misma firma (como es de esperarse, utilize estos dos metodos ultimos:

```
        let from = '0x0A505EA5cA4408078786150d44f5a2034d28b324';
        let nonce = "gZDnr3cVgNpYsoqBmiZQUpH4OE8mdXK0";

        let msgParams = [
            {
              type: 'string',
              name: 'Challenge',
              value: nonce
            }
        ];

        let params = [msgParams, from];
        let method = 'eth_signTypedData';
        let resolve = await web3.currentProvider.request({
            method: method,
            params: params,
            from: from
        });
```

```
        let address = '0x0A505EA5cA4408078786150d44f5a2034d28b324'
        let nonce = "gZDnr3cVgNpYsoqBmiZQUpH4OE8mdXK0";
        let msgParams = [
            {
              type: 'string',
              name: 'Challenge',
              value: nonce
            }
        ]
        var eth = new Eth(web3.currentProvider)
        let resolve = await eth.signTypedData(msgParams, address)
```

Ejemplos de lo que ya utilize:

> **Sign Typed Data** & **Sign Typed Data with Ethjs** del siguiente link:
>
> https://danfinlay.github.io/js-eth-personal-sign-examples/
>
> Y estos otros:
>
> https://github.com/amaurymartiny/login-with-metamask-demo
>
> https://www.toptal.com/ethereum/one-click-login-flows-a-metamask-tutorial
>
> Estuve leyendo esta documentacion:
>
> https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#ethereum-json-rpc-methods
>
> https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#methods